# Check if there's an existing input on the previous schedules using LAG()

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I've asked this question before, unfortunately I wasn't clear on the details of my question, so I'll simplify my previous question:

[Check if there's an existing record on the day before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59747074/check-if-theres-an-existing-record-on-the-day-before/59751577#59751577)

---

How do we do this using `LAG()`? I have an issue processing this because of the `NULL` value. Basically what I want to achieve is that **prevrecordin** and **prevrecordout** columns will display logs a day before or a schedule before the date based on **recordin** and **recordout**.

This is the desired result.

```
+-------------+--------------+------------+-------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
| badgenumber | scheduledate | schedulein | scheduleout |      recordin      |     recordout      |    prevrecordin    |   prevrecordout    |
+-------------+--------------+------------+-------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|          10 | 2019-12-21   | 6:00:00 AM | 2:00:00 PM  | 2019-12-21 5:18 am | 2019-12-21 2:12 pm | NULL               | NULL               |
|          10 | 2019-12-23   | 8:00:00 AM | 5:00:00 PM  | 2019-12-23 7:35 am | 2019-12-23 5:03 pm | 2019-12-21 5:18 am | 2019-12-21 2:12 pm |
|          10 | 2019-12-24   | 8:00:00 AM | 5:00:00 PM  | NULL               | NULL               | 2019-12-23 7:35 am | 2019-12-23 5:03 pm |
|          10 | 2019-12-25   | 8:00:00 AM | 5:00:00 PM  | NULL               | NULL               | NULL               | NULL               |
|          10 | 2019-12-26   | 8:00:00 AM | 5:00:00 PM  | 2019-12-26 7:48 am | 2019-12-26 5:05 pm | NULL               | NULL               |
|          10 | 2019-12-27   | 8:00:00 AM | 5:00:00 PM  | 2019-12-27 7:41 am | 2019-12-27 5:02 pm | 2019-12-26 7:48 am | 2019-12-26 5:05 pm |
|          10 | 2019-12-28   | 8:00:00 AM | 5:00:00 PM  | 2019-12-28 7:35 am | 2019-12-28 5:07 pm | 2019-12-27 7:41 am | 2019-12-27 5:02 pm |
|          10 | 2019-12-30   | 8:00:00 AM | 5:00:00 PM  | NULL               | NULL               | 2019-12-28 7:35 am | 2019-12-28 5:07 pm |
|          10 | 2019-12-31   | 8:00:00 AM | 5:00:00 PM  | NULL               | NULL               | NULL               | NULL               |
|          10 | 2020-01-01   | 8:00:00 AM | 5:00:00 PM  | NULL               | NULL               | NULL               | NULL               |
|          10 | 2020-01-02   | 8:00:00 AM | 5:00:00 PM  | 2020-01-02 7:41 am | 2020-01-02 5:16 pm | NULL               | NULL               |
|          10 | 2020-01-03   | 8:00:00 AM | 5:00:00 PM  | 2020-01-03 7:50 am | 2020-01-03 5:05 pm | 2020-01-02 7:41 am | 2020-01-02 5:16 pm |
|          10 | 2020-01-04   | 8:00:00 AM | 5:00:00 PM  | 2020-01-04 7:41 am | 2020-01-04 5:04 pm | 2020-01-03 7:50 am | 2020-01-03 5:05 pm |
+-------------+--------------+------------+-------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

This is the result that I got.

SQL Fiddle

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ef8d9/1

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    ([badgenumber] int, [scheduledate] varchar(10), [schedulein] varchar(10), [scheduleout] varchar(10), [recordin] DATETIME, [recordout] DATETIME)
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    ([badgenumber], [scheduledate], [schedulein], [scheduleout], [recordin], [recordout])
VALUES
    (10, '2019-12-21', '6:00:00 AM', '2:00:00 PM', '2019-12-21 5:18 am', '2019-12-21 2:12 pm'),
    (10, '2019-12-23', '8:00:00 AM', '5:00:00 PM', '2019-12-23 7:35 am', '2019-12-23 5:03 pm'),
    (10, '2019-12-24', '8:00:00 AM', '5:00:00 PM', NULL, NULL),
    (10, '2019-12-25', '8:00:00 AM', '5:00:00 PM', NULL, NULL),
    (10, '2019-12-26', '8:00:00 AM', '5:00:00 PM', '2019-12-26 7:48 am', '2019-12-26 5:05 pm'),
    (10, '2019-12-27', '8:00:00 AM', '5:00:00 PM', '2019-12-27 7:41 am', '2019-12-27 5:02 pm'),
    (10, '2019-12-28', '8:00:00 AM', '5:00:00 PM', '2019-12-28 7:35 am', '2019-12-28 5:07 pm'),
    (10, '2019-12-30', '8:00:00 AM', '5:00:00 PM', NULL, NULL),
    (10, '2019-12-31', '8:00:00 AM', '5:00:00 PM', NULL, NULL),
    (10, '2020-01-01', '8:00:00 AM', '5:00:00 PM', NULL, NULL),
    (10, '2020-01-02', '8:00:00 AM', '5:00:00 PM', '2020-01-02 7:41 am', '2020-01-02 5:16 pm'),
    (10, '2020-01-03', '8:00:00 AM', '5:00:00 PM', '2020-01-03 7:50 am', '2020-01-03 5:05 pm'),
    (10, '2020-01-04', '8:00:00 AM', '5:00:00 PM', '2020-01-04 7:41 am', '2020-01-04 5:04 pm')
;
```

Query.

```
SELECT *, (case when datediff(day,
                           lag(recordin) over (partition by badgenumber order by recordin),
                           recordin
                          ) >= 1
             then lag(recordin) over (partition by badgenumber order by recordin)
             else null
       end) as prevrecordin,
       (case when datediff(day,
                           lag(recordout) over (partition by badgenumber order by recordout),
                           recordout
                          ) >= 1
             then lag(recordout) over (partition by badgenumber order by recordout)
             else null
       end) as prevrecordout FROM Table1 ORDER BY scheduledate
```

This is the query that I'm trying to fix. from https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035/gordon-linoff on my previous question [Check if there's an existing record on the day before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59747074/check-if-theres-an-existing-record-on-the-day-before/59751577#59751577)

```
....
(case when datediff(day,
                           lag(recordin) over (partition by badgenumber order by recordin),
                           recordin
                          ) >= 1
             then lag(recordin) over (partition by badgenumber order by recordin)
             else null
       end) as prevrecordin,
       (case when datediff(day,
                           lag(recordout) over (partition by badgenumber order by recordout),
                           recordout
                          ) >= 1
             then lag(recordout) over (partition by badgenumber order by recordout)
             else null
       end) as prevrecordout,
....
```

I can't find a way to solve this as well because there are schedules wherein they are near the next day or less than 24 hours/1 day, I'm planning to use **scheduledate** as a parameter for **prevrecordin** and **prevrecordout**, is there a way to do this?

This is the table.

```
+-------------+--------------+------------+-------------+--------------------+--------------------+
| badgenumber | scheduledate | schedulein | scheduleout |      recordin      |     recordout      |
+-------------+--------------+------------+-------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|          10 | 21/12/2019   | 6:00:00 AM | 2:00:00 PM  | 21/12/2019 5:18 am | 21/12/2019 2:12 pm |
|          10 | 23/12/2019   | 8:00:00 AM | 5:00:00 PM  | 23/12/2019 7:35 am | 23/12/2019 5:03 pm |
|          10 | 24/12/2019   | 8:00:00 AM | 5:00:00 PM  | NULL               | NULL               |
|          10 | 25/12/2019   | 8:00:00 AM | 5:00:00 PM  | NULL               | NULL               |
|          10 | 26/12/2019   | 8:00:00 AM | 5:00:00 PM  | 26/12/2019 7:48 am | 26/12/2019 5:05 pm |
|          10 | 27/12/2019   | 8:00:00 AM | 5:00:00 PM  | 27/12/2019 7:41 am | 27/12/2019 5:02 pm |
|          10 | 28/12/2019   | 8:00:00 AM | 5:00:00 PM  | 28/12/2019 7:35 am | 28/12/2019 5:07 pm |
|          10 | 30/12/2019   | 8:00:00 AM | 5:00:00 PM  | NULL               | NULL               |
|          10 | 31/12/2019   | 8:00:00 AM | 5:00:00 PM  | NULL               | NULL               |
|          10 | 01/01/2020   | 8:00:00 AM | 5:00:00 PM  | NULL               | NULL               |
|          10 | 02/01/2020   | 8:00:00 AM | 5:00:00 PM  | 02/01/2020 7:41 am | 02/01/2020 5:16 pm |
|          10 | 03/01/2020   | 8:00:00 AM | 5:00:00 PM  | 03/01/2020 7:50 am | 03/01/2020 5:05 pm |
|          10 | 04/01/2020   | 8:00:00 AM | 5:00:00 PM  | 04/01/2020 7:41 am | 04/01/2020 5:04 pm |
+-------------+--------------+------------+-------------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

Comment: As mentioned before, you encourage others to help by posting a MVCE - that includes a script to create your schema with the appropriate keys and sample data.

Comment: You have to make your question complete here. I wont be clicking link to understand what you want. Right now I see data and output but not logic about what you are trying to do or why is NULL a problem

Comment: @SMor give me a moment, I'll add a MVCE.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza, give me a moment, I'll complete all the details, apologies for this matter.

Comment: @SMor I added SQL Fiddle. please check. Thank you.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I added the SQL Fiddle.

Comment: so what is the error between sqlfiddle and your desire result

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza my desired result is that prevrecordin and prevrecordout should display the record before (a schedule before) recordin and recordout. please check my updated post, the **Desired Result** portion.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza example, 2019-12-23 should display 2019-12-21's value in column prevrecordin and prevrecordout, and so on.

Comment: 23 already display 21, so again where is the error ? Can you have multiple records for same day? If dont should be very easy

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza 2019-12-24 should display 2019-12-23 and not NULL, 2019-12-30 should display 2019-12-28 and not NULL. 2019-12-26 should be NULL,  and 2020-01-02 should be NULL

Comment: Can you have multiple records for same day? If dont should be very easy

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza It can't, it overwrites existing record and replaces it with the latest one, so all data within the same day from every badge number are the latest record only.

Comment: Is this what you need ? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ef8d9/10

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I couldn't thank you enough, I need to study recursive CTE again, thank you!

Comment: You should. But that isnt recursive that is just self join.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I'm just curious, this will work with LAG as well, right?

Comment: Nope. because you can use  LAG(scheduledate) but you want the recordin value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create an incremental id so you can get the previous row info using a self join:

**[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ef8d9/14)**

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT *, row_number() over (partition by badgenumber order by scheduledate) as rn
    FROM Table1
)
SELECT C1.* , C2.recordin as prevrecordin
            , C2.recordout as prevrecordout
FROM CTE C1
LEFT JOIN CTE C2
  ON C1.rn = C2.rn+1
  AND C1.badgenumber = c2.badgenumber
;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| badgenumber | scheduledate | schedulein | scheduleout |             recordin |            recordout | rn |         prevrecordin |        prevrecordout |
|-------------|--------------|------------|-------------|----------------------|----------------------|----|----------------------|----------------------|
|          10 |   2019-12-21 | 6:00:00 AM |  2:00:00 PM | 2019-12-21T05:18:00Z | 2019-12-21T14:12:00Z |  1 |               (null) |               (null) |
|          10 |   2019-12-23 | 8:00:00 AM |  5:00:00 PM | 2019-12-23T07:35:00Z | 2019-12-23T17:03:00Z |  2 | 2019-12-21T05:18:00Z | 2019-12-21T14:12:00Z |
|          10 |   2019-12-24 | 8:00:00 AM |  5:00:00 PM |               (null) |               (null) |  3 | 2019-12-23T07:35:00Z | 2019-12-23T17:03:00Z |
|          10 |   2019-12-25 | 8:00:00 AM |  5:00:00 PM |               (null) |               (null) |  4 |               (null) |               (null) |
|          10 |   2019-12-26 | 8:00:00 AM |  5:00:00 PM | 2019-12-26T07:48:00Z | 2019-12-26T17:05:00Z |  5 |               (null) |               (null) |
|          10 |   2019-12-27 | 8:00:00 AM |  5:00:00 PM | 2019-12-27T07:41:00Z | 2019-12-27T17:02:00Z |  6 | 2019-12-26T07:48:00Z | 2019-12-26T17:05:00Z |
|          10 |   2019-12-28 | 8:00:00 AM |  5:00:00 PM | 2019-12-28T07:35:00Z | 2019-12-28T17:07:00Z |  7 | 2019-12-27T07:41:00Z | 2019-12-27T17:02:00Z |
|          10 |   2019-12-30 | 8:00:00 AM |  5:00:00 PM |               (null) |               (null) |  8 | 2019-12-28T07:35:00Z | 2019-12-28T17:07:00Z |
|          10 |   2019-12-31 | 8:00:00 AM |  5:00:00 PM |               (null) |               (null) |  9 |               (null) |               (null) |
|          10 |   2020-01-01 | 8:00:00 AM |  5:00:00 PM |               (null) |               (null) | 10 |               (null) |               (null) |
|          10 |   2020-01-02 | 8:00:00 AM |  5:00:00 PM | 2020-01-02T07:41:00Z | 2020-01-02T17:16:00Z | 11 |               (null) |               (null) |
|          10 |   2020-01-03 | 8:00:00 AM |  5:00:00 PM | 2020-01-03T07:50:00Z | 2020-01-03T17:05:00Z | 12 | 2020-01-02T07:41:00Z | 2020-01-02T17:16:00Z |
|          10 |   2020-01-04 | 8:00:00 AM |  5:00:00 PM | 2020-01-04T07:41:00Z | 2020-01-04T17:04:00Z | 13 | 2020-01-03T07:50:00Z | 2020-01-03T17:05:00Z |
```

EDIT:

```
SELECT C1.*
     , lag(recordin)  over (partition by badgenumber order by scheduledate) as prevrecordin
     , lag(recordout) over (partition by badgenumber order by scheduledate) as prevrecordout
FROM Table1 C1;
```

Comment: Usually you don't second guess Gordon answers, but I took a second look and the only think you had to change is `ORDER BY scheduledate`.